# What's the difference between "Framing Lumber" and "Framing Studs"?

Tags: wood, framing, studs, lumber, timber-framing

The Home Depot website has these two as categories under Dimensional Lumber.

Why would one want to exclude items from one category during a search for wood to use in a project?

What is the difference?

[image: Screenshot of HomeDepot.com]

Comment: Ed is correct - ...but mostly, because their website is very sub-par at helping you find anything. Verified multiple times in multiple ways over the past few months, as well as less intensively over many years.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Studs are cut to length at the mill so you can build your 8’ walls without cutting the ends off the top and bottom plates with studs make a quick tilt up wall, the rest is true 8’ 10’ 12’ .  Note if remodeling verify length prior to building a wall.

Comment: Learn something new every day+

Comment: "Framing Studs" are also referred to as "Pre-cut".

Comment: If you click the studs category, you get 3, 4, and 6" boards cut to 96, 92 5/8, and 104 5/8.  So basically, any wood meant to be vertical in a typical house.  Ed's answer is talking mostly about the 92 5/8 boards for an 8' wall and the 104 5/8 for a 9' wall.

Comment: I was (today) days old when I learned that. I though the stores were always trying to short change me! :)

Comment: Although The Home Depot doesn't use if this way it can also be used to describe the grade of lumber.  "Stud" grade is one of the low strength grades of lumber since a stud only experiences compression forces.  Framing grade lumber is usually straighter and stronger, having less flaws and is used for rafters and joists where both compression and tension loads are experienced.

Comment: Are you sure it is all about the size? Must be something else too. There are studs and framing lumbers in the same size. so why call them with different names?